# Issue with clearing dialog values in AEM

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

I have one page which has two cq dialogs.Assume it is dialog A and dialog B. Each dialog has 4 panels `(CQ.Ext.Panel)`.
It is working independently. The issue here is when I do the toggle between these two dialogs, dialog A is having dialog B values and dialog B is having dialog A. I am just thinking to clear all the things while closing the dialog. I tried to clear panel values and get the component and removed like `Ext.getCmp(‘comp-name').removeAll();

I just overridden the CQ.Dialog.CANCEL behavior

```
{
    text: "Custom Button",
    handler: function() {
        Ext.getCmp('comp-name').removeAll();
    }
}
```

But these approaches are not fixing the issues. Could anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: I guess your dialog panels is a reference to the same component or its use same stores. Can you share abit more code or extend description?

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not very clear but if this is the problem with component composition this link could be the approach. https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/cqinclude-namespace.html